# maven.repository.redhat.com Nexus Proxy

Tags: proxy, nexus, sonatype

I setup maven.repository.redhat.com as a proxy in Nexus 2.11.3-01

But I am only getting a few artifacts. 
"Browse Index" and "Browse remote" show all artifacts. But "Browse Storage" only shows 2 artifacts. I did not do anything to get those 2 artifacts.. they just showed up automatically.

So when building my maven projects that has a dependency to

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.jboss.bom.eap</groupId>
     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools</artifactId>
     <version>6.4.2.GA</version>
     <type>pom</type>
     <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

I get :

[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find org.jboss.bom.eap:jboss-javaee-6.0-with-tools:pom:6.4.2.GA in https://nexus.xxx.com:8443/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of xxx-nexus-repository has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 98, column 25

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artifacts show up in the storage tab when they are requested through the proxy.  Something requested these through nexus.  You can check the request.log file in sonatype-work/nexus/logs to see what did this.

The failure to download the pom was cached by Maven, it is not going to try again until it's cache timeout expires or you force an update.  Try running the build again with the "-U" flag to force a new check.

If you're still having problems after that see here:

https://support.sonatype.com/entries/21437881-Troubleshooting-Artifact-Download-Failures